# A different kind of math problem

Tags: mathematics

**A different kind of math problem**

$\text{If }$$(2+5=8),\ (8-3=1),\ \text{and}\ (4+3 = 9),$
$\text{Then, what is } (8-6+5) ?$

---

**Bonus:**

$\text{If }(8 - 2 + 7 + \text{P} = \text{A})$,
$\text{Then what is } (6 - 5 + 4)?$

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but it's very hard to search for ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> These are 7-segment digital displays, where the result is an inclusive OR.
>
>  8-6 leaves only the top right vertical; adding that to 5 gives 9.

Bonus answer edited in after initial:

> (8-2+7+P) = A
>  8-2 is top left and bottom right verticals.
>  +7 overlaps bottom right, so it's 7 + top left.
>  +P as expected adds the central horizontal and bottom left vertical to give a standard 7-segment display capital A.

So!

> 6-5 is bottom left vertical only.
>  Adding that to 4 makes a capital H.

Comment: Interestingly, subtraction doesn't commute with addition - (8-6)+5 would give a different result to (8+5)-6.

Answer (score 5):

This is obviously not the answer you intended

> In your three initial examples, if you double the smallest number on LHS
>  and subtract 1 from the largest number on LHS
>  all three examples work out.

Examples:

> 2+5=8 -> 2*2+5-1=8 -> 4+4=8
>  8-3=1 -> 8-1-3*2=1 -> 7-6=1
>  4+3=9 -> 4-1+3*2=9 -> 3+6=9

Therefore:

> 8-6+5=? -> 8-1-6+5*2 -> 7-6+10=11